# Determining the Primary Injury limb in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have the following example data set from a survey about injuries and what side they occur on. The injuries are described in columns (Lat_Ankle_Sprain, knee_sprain, shoulder_sprain) that are abbreviated for easier coding and they have values "Left", "Right", "Both", or "NA". Survey respondents then say which of these injuries caused restricted sport participation (Injury_RestrictedParticipation). one, multiple, or no injuries could have caused restricted sport participation. The injuries listed in Injury_RestrictedParticipation are not abbreviated (see below code chunk):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df<- structure(list(Lat_Ankle_Sprain = c("Left", "Right", "Left", 
                                    "Left", "NA", "NA"), Knee_Sprain = c("Right", "Right", "Left", 
                                                                         "Both", "NA", "Left"), Shoulder_Sprain = c("Right", "Left", "NA", 
                                                                                                                    "Right", "Right", "Right"), Injury_RestrictedParticipation = c("Lateral Ankle Sprain (i.e., inversion sprain),Knee Sprain (or ligament tear)", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "Knee Sprain (or ligament tear),Lateral Ankle Sprain (i.e., inversion sprain)", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "Knee Sprain (or ligament tear)", "Knee Sprain (or ligament tear),Shoulder or Arm Strain (e.g., rotator cuff, biceps),Lateral Ankle Sprain (i.e., inversion sprain)", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "NA", "Shoulder or Arm Strain (e.g., rotator cuff, biceps)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -6L))

                                                
abbreviations <- c("Lateral Ankle Sprain (i.e., inversion sprain)" = "Lat_Ankle_Sprain",
                   "Knee Sprain (or ligament tear)" = "Knee_Sprain",
                   "Shoulder or Arm Strain (e.g., rotator cuff, biceps)" =  "Shoulder_Sprain")
```

**The Goal is to determine what side the primary injury occurred on and put this data in a column called "Primary_Injury_Side"**
To determine this, I aim to take the list of injuries in Injury_RestrictedParticipation, find the corresponding columns, and determine what side the injury occurs. If all the injuries occur on the same side (i.e., Left) then that is the Primary_Injury_Side (i.e., Left). However, in cases where multiple injuries are listed and they occur on different sides, Primary_Injury_Side should be "Both". And if no injuries are listed, Primary_Injury_Side should be "None".

I will provide my code that is not quite working below.

```
get_primary_side <- function(injury_names) {
  injuries <- strsplit(as.character(injury_names), "(?<=\\.(?:i\\.e\\.|e\\.g\\.)),", perl = TRUE)[[1]] #splits injury list by comma - but ignores cases were comma is used after e.g. or i.e. within the injury name
  side_values <- sapply(injuries, function(injury) get_side_for_injury(injury))
  
  unique_sides <- unique(side_values[!is.na(side_values)])
  if (length(unique_sides) == 1) {
    return(as.character(unique_sides))
  } else {
    return("Both")
  }
}

get_side_for_injury <- function(injury) {
  side_value <- get_abbrev_column_names(injury)
  if (!is.na(side_value)) {
    return(side_value)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

get_abbrev_column_names <- function(injury_name) {
  return(abbreviations[injury_name])
}

Injury_df <- df %>% 
             mutate(Primary_Injury_Side = case_when(
             is.na(Injury_RestrictedParticipation) ~ "None",
             TRUE ~ get_primary_side(Injury_RestrictedParticipation)))
```

A second aim of mine is to create a column called LowerBody_Injury_Side which takes the Injury_RestrictedParticipation and follows the same logic as above but ignores columns that are associated with the upper body.

Thank you in advance for you help on this! I would love to provide any additional information that may be helpful.

Comment: please check the code for the data imput, I can not reproduce the `df` object with the given code. Consider using `dput(df)`

Comment: @GuedesBF Thank you for your feedback. I realized that there was a typo in the df object. I am provided the dput(df) as you recommended. I hope this is easier to work with

Answer (score 1):

I believe we do not need the Injury... column at all for the first part of the question (correct me if I am wrong).
To get the side column, we can use `case_when`. For complex rowwise logical operations, we need `rowwise`, otherwise `if_any` or `if_all` may do the trick. We need rowwise here.

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(side = case_when(any("Both" %in% c_across(Lat_Ankle_Sprain:Shoulder_Sprain)) ~ "Both",
                            all(c("Left", "Right") %in% c_across(Lat_Ankle_Sprain:Shoulder_Sprain)) ~ "Both",
                            any("Left" %in% c_across(Lat_Ankle_Sprain:Shoulder_Sprain)) ~ "Left",
                            any("Right" %in% c_across(Lat_Ankle_Sprain:Shoulder_Sprain)) ~ "Right",
                            .default = NA))

# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Rowwise: 
  Lat_Ankle_Sprain Knee_Sprain Shoulder_Sprain Injury_RestrictedParticipation                            side 
  <chr>            <chr>       <chr>           <chr>                                                     <chr>
1 Left             Right       Right           Lateral Ankle Sprain (i.e., inversion sprain),Knee Sprai… Both 
2 Right            Right       Left            Knee Sprain (or ligament tear),Lateral Ankle Sprain (i.e… Both 
3 Left             Left        NA              Knee Sprain (or ligament tear)                            Left 
4 Left             Both        Right           Knee Sprain (or ligament tear),Shoulder or Arm Strain (e… Both 
5 NA               NA          Right           NA                                                        Right
6 NA               Left        Right           Shoulder or Arm Strain (e.g., rotator cuff, biceps)       Both 
>
```

Comment: Thanks @GuedesBF, 
This is great! However, I do indeed need the Injury_RestrictedParticipation column to be included. The reason is that this column indicates more 'severe' injuries. For instance if you have a severe Right knee injury, but a minor Left Ankle sprain... I do not want the Side to be "Both -- but rather it should be "Right" because that corresponds to the knee injury (the more severe injury). 

How would I include this information